# as3 embedded images won't appear

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flashdevelop

I'm trying to create something like Assets manager, where I would embed bunch of images in one class and then pass them to other classes for further use. The problem is, after doing all the work, the images simply wont appear, not all of them. From total 41 images I get about 23 to render/display properly. I triple checked all the code, tried in both Flashdevelop and Flash Professional, tried to add each image to it's own MovieClip or Sprite before adding them to stage, tried adding them one by one with addChild method (without using for loop) and still no success... Also there is no compile error (neither syntax).

Is there something like "max embedded image count" for flashdevelop or flash professional?

Here is the code:

```
package  
{
    import flash.display.Bitmap;
    import flash.display.BitmapData;
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.display.Sprite;

public class AssetsLoader extends MovieClip
{
    [Embed(source = "assets/map800x500.jpg")] private var _layer0Class:Class; public var layer0:Bitmap = new _layer0Class();

    [Embed(source = "assets/al/AFR_01.png")] private var AFR_01_Class:Class; public var AFR_01:Bitmap = new AFR_01_Class() as Bitmap;
    [Embed(source = "assets/al/AFR_02.png")] private var AFR_02_Class:Class; public var AFR_02:Bitmap = new AFR_02_Class() as Bitmap;
    [Embed(source = "assets/al/AFR_03.png")] private var AFR_03_Class:Class; public var AFR_03:Bitmap = new AFR_03_Class() as Bitmap;
    [Embed(source = "assets/al/AFR_04.png")] private var AFR_04_Class:Class; public var AFR_04:Bitmap = new AFR_04_Class() as Bitmap;
    [Embed(source = "assets/al/AFR_05.png")] private var AFR_05_Class:Class; public var AFR_05:Bitmap = new AFR_05_Class() as Bitmap;
    [Embed(source = "assets/al/AFR_06.png")] private var AFR_06_Class:Class; public var AFR_06:Bitmap = new AFR_06_Class() as Bitmap;

    [Embed(source = "assets/al/ASI_01.png")] private var ASI_01_Class:Class; public var ASI_01:Bitmap = new ASI_01_Class() as Bitmap;
    [Embed(source = "assets/al/ASI_02.png")] private var ASI_02_Class:Class; public var ASI_02:Bitmap = new ASI_02_Class() as Bitmap;
    [Embed(source = "assets/al/ASI_03.png")] private var ASI_03_Class:Class; public var ASI_03:Bitmap = new ASI_03_Class() as Bitmap;
    [Embed(source = "assets/al/ASI_04.png")] private var ASI_04_Class:Class; public var ASI_04:Bitmap = new ASI_04_Class() as Bitmap;
    [Embed(source = "assets/al/ASI_05.png")] private var ASI_05_Class:Class; public var ASI_05:Bitmap = new ASI_05_Class() as Bitmap;
    [Embed(source = "assets/al/ASI_06.png")] private var ASI_06_Class:Class; public var ASI_06:Bitmap = new ASI_06_Class() as Bitmap;
    [Embed(source = "assets/al/ASI_07.png")] private var ASI_07_Class:Class; public var ASI_07:Bitmap = new ASI_07_Class() as Bitmap;
    [Embed(source = "assets/al/ASI_08.png")] private var ASI_08_Class:Class; public var ASI_08:Bitmap = new ASI_08_Class() as Bitmap;
    [Embed(source = "assets/al/ASI_09.png")] private var ASI_09_Class:Class; public var ASI_09:Bitmap = new ASI_09_Class() as Bitmap;
    [Embed(source = "assets/al/ASI_10.png")] private var ASI_10_Class:Class; public var ASI_10:Bitmap = new ASI_10_Class() as Bitmap;
    [Embed(source = "assets/al/ASI_11.png")] private var ASI_11_Class:Class; public var ASI_11:Bitmap = new ASI_11_Class() as Bitmap;

    [Embed(source = "assets/al/AUS_01.png")] private var AUS_01_Class:Class; public var AUS_01:Bitmap = new AUS_01_Class() as Bitmap;
    [Embed(source = "assets/al/AUS_02.png")] private var AUS_02_Class:Class; public var AUS_02:Bitmap = new AUS_02_Class() as Bitmap;
    [Embed(source = "assets/al/AUS_03.png")] private var AUS_03_Class:Class; public var AUS_03:Bitmap = new AUS_03_Class() as Bitmap;
    [Embed(source = "assets/al/AUS_04.png")] private var AUS_04_Class:Class; public var AUS_04:Bitmap = new AUS_04_Class() as Bitmap;

    [Embed(source = "assets/al/EUR_01.png")] private var EUR_01_Class:Class; public var EUR_01:Bitmap = new EUR_01_Class() as Bitmap;
    [Embed(source = "assets/al/EUR_02.png")] private var EUR_02_Class:Class; public var EUR_02:Bitmap = new EUR_02_Class() as Bitmap;
    [Embed(source = "assets/al/EUR_03.png")] private var EUR_03_Class:Class; public var EUR_03:Bitmap = new EUR_03_Class() as Bitmap;
    [Embed(source = "assets/al/EUR_04.png")] private var EUR_04_Class:Class; public var EUR_04:Bitmap = new EUR_04_Class() as Bitmap;
    [Embed(source = "assets/al/EUR_05.png")] private var EUR_05_Class:Class; public var EUR_05:Bitmap = new EUR_05_Class() as Bitmap;
    [Embed(source = "assets/al/EUR_06.png")] private var EUR_06_Class:Class; public var EUR_06:Bitmap = new EUR_06_Class() as Bitmap;
    [Embed(source = "assets/al/EUR_07.png")] private var EUR_07_Class:Class; public var EUR_07:Bitmap = new EUR_07_Class() as Bitmap;

    [Embed(source = "assets/al/NAM_01.png")] private var NAM_01_Class:Class; public var NAM_01:Bitmap = new NAM_01_Class() as Bitmap;
    [Embed(source = "assets/al/NAM_02.png")] private var NAM_02_Class:Class; public var NAM_02:Bitmap = new NAM_02_Class() as Bitmap;
    [Embed(source = "assets/al/NAM_03.png")] private var NAM_03_Class:Class; public var NAM_03:Bitmap = new NAM_03_Class() as Bitmap;
    [Embed(source = "assets/al/NAM_04.png")] private var NAM_04_Class:Class; public var NAM_04:Bitmap = new NAM_04_Class() as Bitmap;
    [Embed(source = "assets/al/NAM_05.png")] private var NAM_05_Class:Class; public var NAM_05:Bitmap = new NAM_05_Class() as Bitmap;
    [Embed(source = "assets/al/NAM_06.png")] private var NAM_06_Class:Class; public var NAM_06:Bitmap = new NAM_06_Class() as Bitmap;
    [Embed(source = "assets/al/NAM_07.png")] private var NAM_07_Class:Class; public var NAM_07:Bitmap = new NAM_07_Class() as Bitmap;
    [Embed(source = "assets/al/NAM_08.png")] private var NAM_08_Class:Class; public var NAM_08:Bitmap = new NAM_08_Class() as Bitmap;
    [Embed(source = "assets/al/NAM_09.png")] private var NAM_09_Class:Class; public var NAM_09:Bitmap = new NAM_09_Class() as Bitmap;

    [Embed(source = "assets/al/SAM_01.png")] private var SAM_01_Class:Class; public var SAM_01:Bitmap = new SAM_01_Class() as Bitmap;
    [Embed(source = "assets/al/SAM_02.png")] private var SAM_02_Class:Class; public var SAM_02:Bitmap = new SAM_02_Class() as Bitmap;
    [Embed(source = "assets/al/SAM_03.png")] private var SAM_03_Class:Class; public var SAM_03:Bitmap = new SAM_03_Class() as Bitmap;
    [Embed(source = "assets/al/SAM_04.png")] private var SAM_04_Class:Class; public var SAM_04:Bitmap = new SAM_04_Class() as Bitmap;

    public var allTerritories:Array =  [AFR_01, AFR_02, AFR_03, AFR_04, AFR_05, AFR_06,
                                        ASI_01, ASI_02, ASI_03, ASI_04, ASI_05, ASI_06, ASI_07, ASI_08, ASI_09, ASI_10, ASI_11,
                                        AUS_01, AUS_02, AUS_03, AUS_04,
                                        EUR_01, EUR_02, EUR_03, EUR_04, EUR_05, EUR_06, EUR_07,
                                        NAM_01, NAM_02, NAM_03, NAM_04, NAM_05, NAM_06, NAM_07, NAM_08, NAM_09,
                                        SAM_01, SAM_02, SAM_03, SAM_04];

    public var alphaContainer:MovieClip = new MovieClip();

    public function AssetsLoader() 
    {
        for (var i:int = 0; i < allTerritories.length; i++) 
        {
            alphaContainer.addChild(allTerritories[i]);
            alphaContainer.getChildAt(i).alpha = 1;
        }
    }
}
}
```

In another class I'm adding "alphaContainer" to stage:

```
package  
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;

    [SWF(width = "800", height = "500", backgroundColor = "#222222", frameRate = "60")]
    public class GameMap extends MovieClip 
    {
        public var map:AssetsLoader = new AssetsLoader();

        public function GameMap() 
        {
            if (stage) init();
            else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);

        }

        private function init():void 
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
            addChild(map.alphaContainer);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: are you sure that those images simply overlay each other, and thus you can't see them?

Comment: all images are in png format with transparency, and all of them are pre-made in photoshop precisely to fit in the whole frame without overlapping, and in photoshop they look fine. so I don't think that's the case... since I'm bugging my head for days about this, my best guess is that it has something to do with flash Bitmap limits (http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/size-limits-swf-bitmap-files.html), but I'm not sure...

Answer (score 0):

I once had a similar problem, and when I run my SWF in a debugger, it turned out that there's some runtime library missing which is required for loading embedded content. It was related to a compiler warning which appeared in my command line when compiling:

```
Warning: This compilation unit did not have a factoryClass specified in Frame metadata to load the configured runtime shared libraries. To compile without runtime shared libraries either set the -static-link-runtime-shared-libraries option to true or remove the -runtime-shared-libraries option.
```

When I added the `-static-link-runtime-shared-libraries` option, it started working.

Maybe the cause of your problem is the same?